# Collection with autoCleanup by age

Tags: java, collections

I have build a controller interface, that encapsulates access to certain objects, coming from a database. To reduce DB load, I would like to cache those objects in a list. Meaning: when some one accesses the requests the same object from the controller within a certain time frame, it should be taken from a cache / list.

This list should automatically delete objects that where not requested for some time (let's say: 30 seconds).

Is there a ready to go implementation of such a list?

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: I think you can achieve this with caching mechanism like EhCache, Memcached. You can set a Key and collection as value with a expiration time for that key. For every request you can reset the Expire time. Consider redis if you want more operations on the list with expire time.

Comment: Thanks, ehChache was realy a good hint. Never heared about it before, but was so easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

I can just implement a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). It is easy to implement and no age handling is needed

The other option is to use an O/R mapper with cache function like [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html)

Comment: This is a Web Application, If the load becomes high, the circular buffers index can get filled (int has a max limit). This option is not scalable.

Comment: int max value is 2 147 483 647. Max old of a Object is 30 sec. so we will get problem if the circular buffer is full and all objects are jung. This means that the server got 2 147 483 647 different requests in 30 sec. The database should contains 2 147 483 647 unique items. nice.